# On Verdier duality

Tags: sheaf-theory, duality-theorems, sheaf-cohomology, coherent-sheaves

The following statement is quoted from "Verdier duality" in wiki:

If $X$ is a finite-dimensional locally compact space, and $D^b(X)$ the bounded  derived category of sheaves of abelian groups over $X$, then the Verdier dual is a contravariant functor
$D: D^b(X) \rightarrow D^b(X)$
defined by
$D(\mathcal{F}) = RHom(\mathcal{F},\omega_X)$

It has the following properties:

$D^2(\mathcal{F})\cong \mathcal{F}$ for sheaves with constructible cohomology.

(Intertwining of functors $f_*$ and $f_!$) If $f$ is a continuous map from $X$ to $Y$ then there is an isomorphism
$D(Rf_{\ast}(\mathcal{F})) \cong Rf_!D(\mathcal{F})$.

This is the page in wiki for "Verdier duality". I don't understand why $\mathcal{F}$ should have constructible cohomology (the first property). Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Isn't that just one of the hypotheses?

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez, I have modified the question. Thanks!

Comment: is there any comment for this problem?

Comment: Well if you look at the proof of this theorem, you will clearly see that constructible cohomology is highly used. Is a reference of the proof enough for an answer ?

Comment: It's not true without some finiteness hypothesis on the sheaf $\mathcal{F}$; this is exactly analogous to what happens for vector spaces!